# Disabling 304 HTTP tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, caching

I have recently started using F5's BigIP Web Accelerator to proxy my tomcat web server.  There may be a bug in caching the content from tomcat that is triggered by the HTTP response 304 (see: http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/12000/800/sol12802.html).

In order to prove that this is the correct theory - I'd like to temporarily disable 304 HTTP responses from the tomcat server to see if it fixes the issue.

The tomcat version is 7.0.26-1 on Ubuntu.  Setting the  in context.xml and restarting tomcat did not resolve the issue.

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible per configuration in tomcat. I hardly think so, at least  for non static files. (But i do not know).

But you asked for suggestions, so i would try to remove the request and response headers which are responsible for HTTP 304 responses. 
So in the response this would be the `ETag` header. In the request it would be the `If-None-Match`  and `If-Modified-Since` header.

how you could achieve this depends on your environment.You could write a Java EE filter for your application which removes them or globally in tomcat you could use a valve(I think the latter is a tomcat specific possibility).

If you have an apache with mod_jk in front of your tomcat you could use mod_headers to unset the headers (visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) or if apache itself is generating the headers simply turn of ETag generation.
The last possibility i could think of is that your f5 device provides a method to remove headers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, it gives me something to go on.